# HTML5 i tag validity with icons

Tags: html, seo, icons, glyphicons

I have been using Bootstrap to build my site, but in doing so and researching SEO, I've discovered that using the `i` tags with glyphicons is not technically "valid" HTML. Is there a definitive rule that says that `i` tags can be used in this way without effecting markup validity without effecting SEO?

As part of this issue, I am also trying to satisfy a complaint that my anchor text does not describe its destination:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Accountant", "Service")">
     <div class="service-icon">
           <div class="icon-book-1 icon-medium-effect icon-effect-2"></div>
     </div>
</a>
```

This produces the desired visual effect, however I can't add anchor text else it will obviously be displayed on the screen. Normally an image would have been used within the anchor and I could have displayed `alt` text, so I'm stuck as to where best to put this "descriptive text".

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? You don't need to use `i` tags anymore, `<spans>` work as well.

Comment: Yes just noticed it's Bootstrap 3, but if I change it to <span> the alignments of the icons change, which I wouldn't expect to happen. Thanks for pointing this option out though!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 5):

**Don’t use `i`.**

The [`i` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-i-element) has a meaning which isn’t appropriate for general icons:

> […] a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, transliteration, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts.

Reasons why some people use(d) `i` as hook for showing icons (via CSS)  might be:

- The term "icon" starts with *i*.
- The element name is short.

**Use `span` instead**, which is a *meaningless* element.

---

If the icon is relevant content (important for understanding/using your page), consider using the `img` element instead, which allows you to use the `alt` attribute.

You should use CSS for decorative icons only. If that’s not possible:

If you link this icon and the link doesn’t contain any content (no text, no `img`, …), i.e. it only contains an *empty* element, then you should provide some content in the HTML. Otherwise, visitors without CSS support, screen reader users, etc. won’t be able to use your link. If you don’t want to include content for design reasons, hide it visually. [More details in my related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32854051/1591669).

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like `<span class="sr-only">Your Text</span>` to improve the accessibility.

`.sr-only` is a built-in Bootstrap class to make it easier to provide useful text to screen readers when you also do not want that text to appear visually on the screen.