# What is the proper use of Microdata markup?

Tags: html, microdata

I am adding Microdata to my site and would like to know if there is a problem with this markup:

```html
<span class="createdate" itemprop="dateCreated"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> 7-15-2013</span>
```

Or should I use this:

```html
<span class="createdate"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span itemprop="dateCreated">7-15-2013</span></span>
```

Basically, does Microdata markup must follow the text, and does it have a problem with an icon or `span` in front of the text?

Comment: simple answer ,  http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippet

Answer (score 2):

The [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values) will be the `textContent` of the `span` element with the `itemprop`.

So I guess both cases would be fine.

#### Side notes

- Your date format is not correct. See [Schema.org’s `dateCreated`](http://schema.org/dateCreated). You must use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), i.e., `2013-07-15`.
- Why not use the [`time` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)? [Microdata uses the datetime value](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#values) from its `datetime` attribute (or element content, if you don’t specify the attribute).
- You [should not use the `i` element for icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669).

Comment: I am using span for icons , since many people here use <i>, I just trow it in so that they would understand what is in the markup. Thhx for the info. And yes I moved to time element for those, but the question was "what if" there is additional markup

Comment: Testing markup here , gives you exact info and what you should do/not do google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippet