# HTML5 semantic element for info-box?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Please help me with finding the right HTML5 tag for an info message box:

```
<div class="info-box">
   <div class="info-box-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
   </div>

   <div class="info-box-message">
      <p>In the case of questions or problems, please contact us at the email address <a href="mailto:my@adress.com">my@adsress.com</a></p>
   </div>

</div>
```

Can I use this example?

```
<details class="info-box">
   <div class="info-box-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i>
   </div>

   <summary="info-box-message">
      <p>In the case of questions or problems, please contact us at the email address <a href="mailto:my@adress.com">my@adsress.com</a></p>
   </summary>

</details>
```

Comment: What's your specific problem ?

Comment: I want completely  create my web in html5. My question is can i use element details for info-box?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `details` element in HTML5 (it was part of HTML5 drafts, but got removed before HTML5 was published as Recommendation).

There is no general answer which element to use for an "info-box", as it’s not clear what such an info-box is, and in which context it gets used in your specific case.

It seems that you have added the `div` elements only for styling/scripting reasons, so these can be ignored for deciding which markup to use, as they are meaningless.

It seems that you have added the `i` element for displaying an icon, which is [not appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669). If you *have to* add an empty HTML element for this (instead of using CSS resp. existing elements), use `span` instead.

So the semantic markup for your example might be:

```html
<p class="info-box">
  In the case of questions or problems, please contact us at the email address <a href="mailto:my@example.com">my@example.com</a>
</p>
```

If it’s part of its section’s header, place it in `header`; if part of its section’s footer, place it in `footer`; and if it’s not related to its section’s main content, place it in `aside`.
If it’s representing contact information for the parent `article` (if any), or the `body`, then place it in `address` (possibly itself in `header`/`footer`).
Otherwise, it’s simply part of its section’s main content.