# How to hide text of an anchor tag that uses i element

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor tag that does not have any text in it and just uses the `<i>` element along with `glyphicons`. While doing accessibility testing I found out that anchor tags should have text. One strategy is to [put the text and visibly hide it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631180/link-contain-no-text-showing-error-in-wave-accessibility-evaluation-tool) using CSS.

I hide it visually using this CSS:

```
font: 0;
line-height: 0;
color: transparent;
```

However, this makes the glyphicon go away as well. Is there a way I can just hide the anchor tag but keep the glyphicon as-is?

My achor tag is below for example:

`<a class="something"><i class="glyphicons glyphicons-some-icon"></a>`

Comment: for what i know there is no such feature where child element can ignore parent style ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080365/css-to-prevent-child-element-from-inheriting-parent-styles  and please correct me if im wrong

Comment: Why don't you add some text in a `<span>` and then hide that instead?

Comment: You're looking for `aria-label`.

Comment: @SLaks won't I have to add an extra label with aria-label?

Comment: @SLaks If I add `aria-label` I get an error `broken ARIA reference`