# Is an anchor element required to have included text?

Tags: html, anchor, standards, definition

It is possible to define an anchor without text? I. e. without inline text.

```
<p>some text <a name="anchor47"></a> and further text</p>
```

I don't find any information in the standard. Usually I would write my HTML as

```
<p>some <a name="anchor47">text</a> and further text</p>
```

I just wanted to be sure that my code is accepted by all browsers and check programs...

One check program I used successfully (that means it does not complain if "empty" anchors are there) is [that of w3](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: You're asking a bit of an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info), I think. If all you want is an in-page anchor, just put an ID on the paragraph or a span element. It doesn't have to be an anchor element.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631180/link-contain-no-text-showing-error-in-wave-accessibility-evaluation-tool. Such links are accessibility issues.

Comment: At least wave accessibility evaluation tool will complain - that is a good point to disallow the use of an anchar definition without text. And I'm going to improve my content checker to detect those anchors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's valid, but you could also add a blank space like:

```
<p>some text <a name="anchor47">&nbsp;</a> and further text</p>
```

or you can add text and set the font-size to 0

```
<p>some text <a name="anchor47" style="font-size:0">anchors away!</a> and further text</p>
```

I believe there is a benefit to adding *some* descriptive text in there and hiding it for screen readers. See [here](https://amberwilson.co.uk/blog/are-your-anchor-links-accessible/#accessibility-check) for info on accessibility + anchor links.

However, I believe you should be using an alternative method like adding an ID to a span, h3 tag, etc.

```
<h3 id="anchor">Do you know how to tie an anchor knot?</h3>
```

And your link:

```
<a href="#anchor">Tie an Anchor Knot</a>
```

Comment: The only thing which I want to avoid is the risk to get in the future the work to change potentially 60.000+ anchors in my documentation.

Comment: Thanks to all sharing their knowledge! It helped a lot.