# Microdata Markup - 'Brand > Logo' with Icon Font for Logo

Tags: html, fonts, seo, microdata, rich-snippets

`<a href='' itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Brand' itemprop='brand'><i class="logo" itemprop='logo'></i></a>`

The above `class='logo'` applies a font to the icon element. Can we apply the 'glyph' defined in the class (e.g.,  `font-family: 'AnyFont'; content: '/e600'`) as a [Microdata Markup](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org) DataType ["Brand > Logo](https://schema.org/logo)" to render the Logo in a [rich-snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/?hl=en) the same as a image would render in the rich-snippet?

This doesn't seem likely as an image has a URL based `src="..."` property and a font character does not, none the less I've been researching this I've found no documentation or discussion on this and need to know if the community is aware of a way to make this work if it does't already work. Or do we have to forfeit the many well-known benefits of using an icon-font to display a logo in rich-snippets?

As validation to the common application of microdata to an image and not an font-character we see that [this heavily used microdata generator](http://www.microdatagenerator.com/organization-logos-schema/) doesn't give us an option to apply microdata to an element with a font applied to it. And based on the ['Brand > Logo' documentation](https://schema.org/logo), the only options are `ImageObject` and `URL` (which many very well may believe this answers the question (there's bound to be a way to do this without having to go back 4 years and use an image instead of a font)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `link` element (which [may be used in the `body`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633) in HTML5+Microdata) to provide the URL of the logo:

```html
<a itemprop="brand" href="" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
  <span class="logo"></span>
  <link itemprop="logo" href="logo.png" />
</a>
```

(I used [`span` instead of `i`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669). And for the record, I don’t agree that it’s a good idea to include a site’s logo via CSS instead of HTML.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but even if it works, I can't use this approach as it breaks the W3C Standard for `<link>` tags, http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/use-links. The `<link>` tag should only be nested in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: @id.ot: You are mistaken, it’s perfectly valid in HTML5+Microdata ([details](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55133/17633)).

Comment: Had a feeling I was mistaken, that why I wrote the op and commented. Thank you for your input. Unfortunately your answer didn't include the link that validates compliance and being ignorant to the fact that the `itemprop` extends `<link>` into the `<body>` I had to down the answer. However you're correct and if you can edit your answer to include your linked stackoverflow post, I'll be able to mark the answer as useful. In the meantime this is a solid solution and will mark your answer as "the answer". Thank you @unor.

Comment: @id.ot: Thanks; I added the link to the answer.